# Optimal way to drop unknown elements and rearrange to a specific sequence

Tags: python, list, numpy, dictionary

For context, I wanted to find the most optimal/fastest way to remove unknown elements and rearranging them in numpy arrays [can be in any order]

i.e. I want to rearrange columns_2 to columns_1 and then use the rearranged indices on a numpy array

```
columns_1 = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
columns_2 = ["one", "three", "four", "two", "extra"]
```

One solution I could come up with is like

```
column_idx = {col: idx for idx, col in enumerate(columns_2)}
array[:, [column_idx[col] for col in columns_1]]
```

Is there any better/faster alternative?
Note: Solution must fail if any of the elements of columns_1 is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.index(item)` returns the first index that matches `item` in a list. You can do this:

```
[columns_2.index(col) for col in columns_1]
```

And then create your array. Since it won't have to iterate over unneeded elements of `columns_2` it will be faster. The size of the benefit will depend on the overlap of the lists.

Comment: I had forgotten to add that the solution must fail if any of columns_1 is missing. But your current solution is also something I hadn't considered before, thanks for that. Marked yours as accepted

Comment: You're in luck: list.index(item) raises `ValueError` if `item` is not in the list.